# How to redirect after phoneNumber linking in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need help. I dont know how to detect if the phoneNumber was successfully linked to the user. I want to redirect to other page if action was success. My code is this. *My code works but if I add a function to redirect it doesnt works.

```
function verifyNumber(){

var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phoneNumber');
var signInButtonElement = document.getElementById('sign-in-button');
var inputCode = document.getElementById('code');
var codeButton = document.getElementById('confirm-code');


if(!user.phoneNumber){

  // You also need to provide a button element signInButtonElement
  // which the user would click to complete sign-in.
  // Get recaptcha token. Let's use invisible recaptcha and hook to the button.
  var appVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
      signInButtonElement, {size: 'invisible'});
  // This will wait for the button to be clicked the reCAPTCHA resolved.
  user.linkWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber.value, appVerifier)
    .then(function(confirmationResult) {
      // Ask user to provide the SMS code.
      phoneNumber.style.display = 'none';
      signInButtonElement.style.display = 'none';

      //inputCode.style.display = 'inline-block'
      //codeButton.style.display = 'inline-block'
       var code = window.prompt('Provide your SMS code');
      // Complete sign-in.
      return confirmationResult.confirm(code);
      //updateStatus() doesnt work
    });
    }

 }

 function updateStatus(){
 var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
 if(user.phoneNumber){
    window.location.href = "../home/home.html";
 }else{
    alert('Ha ocurrido un error');
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the async function `confirmationResult.confirm` to complete before checking and redirecting.

```
user.linkWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber.value, appVerifier)
  .then(function(confirmationResult) {
    // Ask user to provide the SMS code.
    phoneNumber.style.display = 'none';
    signInButtonElement.style.display = 'none';

    //inputCode.style.display = 'inline-block'
    //codeButton.style.display = 'inline-block'
    var code = window.prompt('Provide your SMS code');
    // Complete sign-in.
    return confirmationResult.confirm(code);
  })
  .then(() => {
    // Wait for linking to complete before redirecting.
    updateStatus();
  });
}
```